# A Remote Desktop app for Samsung Gear VR

Tags: android, remote-desktop, vr

There are apps like Teamviewer that allows you to access a desktop computer remotely from an iPhone, iPad, or Android. My question is, are there any apps that allow you to access a desktop computer remotely using the Samsung Gear VR headset?

I'd preferably want an app available through either the Oculus app store or the SideloadVR app store, but failing that a Google Cardboard app would be acceptable if it works on Samsung Gear VR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've only found one solution, involving [Stream Theater](http://sideloadvr.com/detail.php?id=14), an app that's not found in the Samsung Gear VR's official Oculus Store, but is instead available through SideloadVR.  In any case, [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GearVR/comments/4cn2km/virtual_desktop_for_gear_vr/) gives instructions on how to use the Stream Theater app as a Remote Desktop.

Other answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are several VNC clients for Cardboard, you'll need some other app to disable Oculus home (it's a toggle, not permanent) so that you can use your gear as if it were a cardboard HMD, and a VNC server client on your target PC.
Personally, I use [Play Cardboard apps on Gear VR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kunkunsoft.cardboardappforgearvr), [VR Remote Desktop Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.chai.cardboardremotedesktop.lite&hl=en), and TightVNC (running as a service on my laptop). The Oculus disabler cost $0.99, but the other two are free. edit: once bigscreenvr finishes their code, it should be available on Oculus home, with the added benefit of upto 4 users in a virtual room, with u pto 3 screens!  code fasta fellahs... *crossed fingers*

Comment: Couldn't you just put the Samsung phone in the Gear VR without connecting it to the metal connector?  That's how I use my iPhone with the Gear VR.

Comment: i suppose you could, but then you lose the touchpad.